# Cannot use object of type WP_Error

Tags: wp-error

```
function im_add_new_term($name,$tax){   
    if($tax == "genre"){      
        return wp_insert_term($name,$tax,array("slug"=>array_search ($name, $genres)))["term_id"];  
    } else {
        return wp_insert_term($name,$tax)["term_id"]; 
    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in
>   /home/pcodecom/demo.p30code.com/multimedia-2/wp-content/plugins/imdb/imdb.php
>   on line 11

Comment: `Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array` means you cannot call it with array notation like `$something['term_id']`, instead, you need to call it with arrow notation like `$someting->term_id`

Comment: `wp_insert_term($name,$tax)->term_id` ok?

Comment: it might work in new PHP, but in old php it might not work. For better compatibility, it is better to create a variable first then use the variable to get the value

Comment: `function im_add_new_term($name,$tax){    
 if($tax == "genre"){        
  $ali = wp_insert_term($name,$tax,array("slug"=>array_search ($name, $genres))); return $ali->term_id;    
 } else {
  $faraji = wp_insert_term($name,$tax); return $faraji->term_id;    
 }
}`

not working

Comment: error :

Undefined property: WP_Error::$term_id in /home/pcodecom/demo.p30code.com/multimedia-2/wp-content/plugins/imdb/imdb.php on line 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's `$genres`? I don't see it defined anywhere.

And `wp_insert_term()` may [return an error](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/#return), so make sure to check if it is an error. So instead of simply doing `return wp_insert_term($name,$tax)["term_id"]`, you could do something like this:

```php
$data = wp_insert_term( $name, $tax );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $data ) ) {
    return $data['term_id'];
}
```

Comment: What's `$genres`? Movie genre

Comment: Ok, just make sure it's defined in your actual code, because I don't see it defined in the question (e.g. `$genres = array( 'foo' => 'Foo' );`). :)